# Drupal custom module civicase is creating but it is returning null value?

Tags: drupal

In my drupal custom module I am creating a case object via

$result = civicrm_api3('case', 'create', $params);

This function on debugging api.php file is returning the case id but in my module it is returning the null value

I want it to return the case id. How would i do so?
Here code Snippet

```
     
function form_test_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
$params = array( 
    'subject' => 'Test case',
    'contact_id' => 64771, 
    'case_type' => 'test', 
);

$case = testcase_create($params);

function testcase_create($params){
    civicrm_initialize(); 
    require_once 'api/api.php';

    try{ 
        $result = civicrm_api3('case', 'create', $params); 
    }
    catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) { 
        $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
        $errorCode = $e->getErrorCode();
        $errorData = $e->getExtraParams();
        return array('error' => $errorMessage, 'error_code' => $errorCode, 'error_data' => $errorData);
    } 
    return $result; // the value of $result is NULL, where as in api.php it was not NULL as seen in debugging
 }
```

Comment: I can able to create case in drupal custom module in earlier civicrm was upgraded that is xml problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a permissions issue, depending on who is the logged-in user when your code runs and whether they have permission to create cases. If you want your code to run anyway regardless of who is logged-in, you could add `'check_permissions' => FALSE` to your api $params.